# Plugin json page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, page-template, json

From a simple plugin I have to create a page where to give data in json form.

```
function create_page_json() {

    $return = array(
        'value1'  => '1',
        'value2'  => 'ok'
    );
    $jdata = json_encode($return);

    $PageGuid = site_url() . "/page-json";
    $my_post  = array( 'post_title'     => 'Page Json',
                 'post_type'      =>  'page',
                 'post_name'      => 'json-page',
                 'post_content'   => $jdata, 
                 'post_status'    => 'publish',
                 'comment_status' => 'closed',
                 'ping_status'    => 'closed',
                 'post_author'    => 1,
                 'menu_order'     => 0,
                 'guid'           => $PageGuid );

    $PageID = wp_insert_post( $my_post, FALSE ); 
}

if( get_page_by_title( 'Page Json' ) == NULL ) 
    add_action( 'init', 'create_page_json' );
```

but in this way I get this

[image]

Instead, I want to get this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hook before the template is loaded and output page content directly:

```
function wpd_output_json_page(){
    if( is_page( 'Page Json' ) ){
        global $post;
        echo $post->post_content;
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpd_output_json_page' );
```